# Generate grid and populate empty cells with div elements

Tags: javascript, grid, lodash

I want to generate some grid by size 6x5 that overall means 30 cells by default though it can have less cells because all cells should be draggable and resizable.

Now I have something following for a default grid

```
_.map(items, (item, i) => {
    return {x: i * 1 % 6, y: Math.floor(i / 6) * 2, w: 1, h: 1, i: i.toString()};
});
```

It populates 30 cells on the grid with `div` elements but if the grid already predefined with some custom cells then need to check which cells are empty and set coordinates x,y and w,h accordingly where there a free space to not make collision with already existing cells.

It should not be anything complicated with the grid, it planning to work simple and as I think to have something similar to that pattern by keeping information in the Array but maybe there are better solutions how to organize it.

```
[
[xxxxxx],
[xxxxxx],
[xxxxxx],
[xxxxxx],
[xxxxxx]
]
```

As I wrote if database returns the information for the grid, it could look like this, for instance,

```
let db = {
0: {x:1,y:0,w:2:h1},
1: {x:4,y:0,w:1:h1},
2: {x:3,y:2,w:2:h2},
}
```

respectively to that information the grid would look like

```
[
[x00x1x],
[xxxxxx],
[xxx22x],
[xxx22x],
[xxxxxx]
]
```

And after that need to refill empty cells with empty `div` elements. But the function specified above didn't check that and causes issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your goal, you want to generate a grid with filled cells according to an array of coordinates and width/height, written like this (there was typos in your question so I rewrote it down here):

```
let db = {
  0: { x: 1, y: 0, w: 2, h: 1 },
  1: { x: 4, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
  2: { x: 3, y: 2, w: 2, h: 2 },
}
```

and it would be represented this way for convenience:

```
x00x1x
xxxxxx
xxx22x
xxx22x
xxxxxx
```

Since you used the ES6 syntax and lodash on your question, I'll use it also in the proposed answer as well, but I want to mention that this would  require changes without lodash and may not work on some system as experimental features are in use here.

Proposed method :

```js
let db = {
    0: { x:1, y:0, w:2, h:1 },
    1: { x:4, y:0, w:1, h:1 },
    2: { x:3, y:2, w:2, h:2 },
};

// Generate the default grid
const emptyGrid = (rows, cols) => 
[...Array(rows).keys()].map((e, row) =>
 [...Array(cols).keys()].map((e, col) =>
   ({ x: col, y: row, w: 0, h: 0 })));

// Generate array of cell coordinates to fill from width and height
const cellCoords = cell => {
    let coords = [];
    for (let i = cell.w - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        for (let j = cell.h - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            coords = [...coords, {x: cell.x + i, y: cell.y + j}];
    return coords;
};

// Generate a grid of rows by cols, filled with optional cells data
const generateGrid = (rows, cols, cells) => {
  cells = cells || [];
 return _.reduce(cells, (grid, cell, index) =>  {
        cellCoords(cell).forEach(({x, y}) =>
         grid[y][x] = {...grid[y][x], ...cell, i: index});
        return grid;
    }, emptyGrid(rows, cols));
}

// Here are some utilities for the snippet exemple
const displayGrid = (grid, target) => {
  grid = _.map(grid, row => _.reduce(row, (s, c) => s + (c.i ? c.i.toString() : 'x'), ''));
    document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = grid.join('<br/>');
}

displayGrid(generateGrid(5, 6), 'output')
displayGrid(generateGrid(5, 6, db), 'output-prefilled')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
Empty Grid:
<div id="output" style="margin:10px"></div>

Prefilled Grid:
<div id="output-prefilled" style="margin:10px"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, you're almost right, it what I meant. Sorry for a late answer and thanks for great example of the code using ES6, it works for me because I'm using babel. I really liked your solution, I have a bit modified it because I'm using third-part libraries and there are some aspects to work with. Your code really helped me to solve the issue. Thanks one more time!